# Android Database to server connectivity

Tags: web-services, rest

I am developing my first App using android. The App will save the messages and contacts of mobile in his database and i want to connect to an online database to store user data. i study the web api is there any other solution to easily solve this issue , reference or code which will help me ??

Comment: Actually you need some server backend. You should look for "Internet of Things".  Probably you will find some easy libraries. E.g. Google Cloud or Amazon Web Services. They have solutions for mobile apps, those can make your live easily.

Comment: can these services redirect my device data to my server ?

Comment: If you have already your own server backend with some REST Api, than forget I've said. It will not help. But if you don't have, you can host it in the cloud and use their infrastructure and libraries.

Comment: Do you only need some libraries for server communication?

Comment: i have nothing at this time i am just collecting information that how to work efficiently , after getting all the knowledge i start my project , so what will be perfect in my case ?

Comment: i am a student of final semester and working on my final project so what kind of services will be easy and perfect in my case ?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/

Comment: Or azure mobile apps

Comment: ok thanks fo sharing these services with me :)